# Angular JS form submission issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to add an entry to my reviews array.

```
 <b>Submit a review</b>
        <form name="submitReviews" ng-controller="ReviewController as reviewCtrl" ng-submit="reviewCtrl.addReview(product)">
            <blockquote>
                <b>Stars : {{reviewCtrl.review.stars}}</b>
                {{reviewCtrl.review.body}}
                <cite>by: {{reviewCtrl.review.author}}</cite>
            </blockquote>
            <select ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.stars">
                <option value="1">1 Star</option>
                <option value="2">2 Star</option>
                <option value="3">3 Star</option>
                <option value="4">4 Star</option>
                <option value="5">5 Star</option>
            </select>
            <textarea ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.body">
            </textarea>
            <label>by: </label>
            <input ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.author" type="email" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Review" />
        </form>
```

The js file :

```
app.controller('ReviewController', function($scope) {
    $scope.review = {};

    $scope.addReview = function (product) {
        product.reviews.push($scope.review);
        $scope.review = {};
    };
});
```

The array to while I want to add(the complete object structure):

```
 var gems = [{
    //First gem
    name: "Dodecahedron",
    price: 2.95,
    description: "great stone",
    specification: "Very Expensive, hand crafted, African made",
    reviews: [{
        stars: 5,
        body: "test review1",
        author: "test1@gmail.com",
    },
        {
            stars: 3,
            body: "not worth the price.",
            author: "test2@gmail.com"
        }],
    canPurchase : true,
    soldOut: false,
    image: [
        { image1 :  "Images/img1.jpeg" },
        { image2 :  "Images/img2.jpeg" }
    ]
}
```

I can see all the information before the form correctly(images and current reviews predefined in the array). When I submit a new review from the HTML page, it should be added to the existing reviews(arr.push). This is not happening.
This controller(ReviewController) is nested inside another controller. Dont know if that make a difference.

Comment: I think you need to declare product.reviews as an array as product.reviews=[ ]; try this

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your form is posting and reloading the page. Pass `$event` into your submit handler and call `$event.preventDefault()` or `return false`

```
 ng-submit="addReview($event, product)"
```

then...

```
$scope.addReview = function ($event, product) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    // ...
};
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying, since I am not saving this value anywhere, i would disappear on a page refresh. I tried your way but does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use not scope, but contoller itself in your controller code.
Use this.reviews, instead of $scope.reviews. you are using controller as syntax, so use controller instance to store variables.

Comment: ##This is not working as well
    app.controller('ReviewController', function() {
        this.review = {};

        this.addReview = function (product) {
            product.reviews.push(this.review);
            this.review = {};
        };
    });

Comment: Hard to work without your code on plunker. Try to not clean the review after adding it to the array, may be it clears in the array after adding it.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the ng-submit is not invoking your addReview() method. Check this first.
If that is the case then you can try the below

As you are using the controllerchange your code in js to below($scope to this). Also the ng-model you are using is reviewCtrl.review so use the same here as well

```
 this.addReview = function (product) {
    product.reviews.push($scope.reviewCtrl.review);
    $scope.reviewCtrl.review = {};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<b>Submit a review</b>
<form name="submitReviews" ng-controller="ReviewController as reviewCtrl" ng-submit="reviewCtrl.addReview()">
    <blockquote>
        <b>Stars : {{reviewCtrl.review.stars}}</b>
        {{reviewCtrl.review.body}}
        <cite>by: {{reviewCtrl.review.author}}</cite>
    </blockquote>
    <select ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.stars">
        <option value="1">1 Star</option>
        <option value="2">2 Star</option>
        <option value="3">3 Star</option>
        <option value="4">4 Star</option>
        <option value="5">5 Star</option>
    </select>
    <textarea ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.body">
    </textarea>
    <label>by: </label>
    <input ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.author" type="email" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Review" />
</form>
```

controller:

```
app.controller('ReviewController', function($scope) {
    $scope.review = {};

    $scope.addReview = function () {
        var review = angular.copy($scope.review);
        // assuming gems is a global variable
        gems.reviews.push(review);
        $scope.review = {};
    };
});
```

I hope this helps :)